# Why would a loop over an empty list hang?

Tags: java

Just a quick curiosity, I wrote this bit of code (I know it's bad code, I have replaced it since).  It is the toString method of a DocumentTreeNode which meant that it was being recursively called in the for loop (like I said, bad idea).  The interesting bit was it hung when the set of children was empty, can anyone explain why that would happen?

Note: `children` is a TreeSet, in this case empty

```
public String toString() {
    MoreObjects.ToStringHelper helper =
            MoreObjects.toStringHelper(getClass())
            .add("parent", this.parent)
            .add("key", this.key)
            .add("value", this.value);
    for (DocumentTreeNode<V> child : children.values()) {
        helper = helper.add("child", child);
    }
    return helper.toString();
}
```

Comment: If it's *really* empty, it doesn't happen. The enhanced for loop would find that `children.values().iterator().hasNext()` is false immediately. I would expect that it's actually an unintentional recursive call to this `toString()` method, i.e. one of `this.parent`, `this.key`, `this.value` is equal to `this`.

Comment: An enhanced `for` loop over a zero-length array or an empty `Iterable` does not hang.  Control just passes through, with zero iterations of the loop body performed.

Comment: Actually, I don't think it is a recursive call - that would fail reasonably quickly with a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Are you a child of your own parent? Does `helper.add()` call `toString()` of the second argument? If yes to both, you have infinite recursion loop right there. May take a while, but you'll eventually get a `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Parent in this scenario is null, the case I have been using has only a root.

Answer (score 2):

You add `parent` to `toString` representation, which calls its `toString`. In turn it is calling `toString` on its children, each of which calls that method on parent again. You've got an infinite loop.

Upd. Although I'd expect that to quickly die with something like stackoverflow. I recommend you to run this in the debugger and step through the code to validate the hypothesis suggested.